# How to generate variables using Asio library?

Tags: c

I have a C program that has a set of variables as input-output (in iomap.iom). I want to confirm that it is possible to generate these variables using the Asio library. How can I check that?

Comment: Are you talking about https://think-async.com/Asio/ ?

Comment: If the library you're using is the one that Barmar found, then it looks like it is included in the Boost library, which in turn means that it is C++ code rather than C code.